# Linux Routing between Linux servers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, route

I am trying to route traffic from server2 to the firewall using server1.
here is the network diagram

1. There is an IPSec site-to-site between 2 firewalls. The remote(right) site IP is 192.168.0.1 and the local(lift) Firewall IP is 192.168.1.1.
2. Local firewall LAN side IP is 172.1.1.254. and Linux server1 IP (1762.1.1.1) can ping 192.168.0.1 adding a static route on server1 via 17.1.1.254.
3. Server1 IP 10.0.0.1 is also connected with server2 IP 10.0.0.254.
4. I added a static route for 192.168.0.1 via server1 IP 10.0.0.1.
   I am not able to ping or access 192.168.0.1 from server2.
   kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: "_here is the network diagram_" Where is the diagram?

Comment: dear sorry I add

Comment: dear sorry
FIrewall1(192.168.0.1)-------(192.1.68.1.1.)firewall2(172.1.1.254)-------(172.1.1.1)Server1(10.0.0.1)---------server2(10.0.0.254)